# How can I make jQuery create a separate instance of this function assigning by class?

Tags: jquery

I have a function (essentially a plug-in) that grabs random images over and over.

The problem is, if there's 2 elements with the same class in a page, it treats them as one...

Ex.

```
[x][x]
[x][x][x]
```

instead of

```
[x][x][x][x][x]
[x][x][x][x][x]
```

*(See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XeNN/) for live demo)*

Is there a way to make it create a separate instance for each of the elements while still using a class as a selector? `i.e., the class is .preview and it has no ID`

```
randomPhoto = function(element,amount){

    x = $(element);     
    img = x.find('img');
    total = img.length;

    img.animate({opacity:0}).hide();

    showImages = function(amount){            
      var used = [];
      var current = []      
       for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
         var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
         used.push(r);
         swap = used;
         used = current;
         current = swap;

           if(r!=used)
             var image = img.eq(r);                 
             image.animate({opacity:1}).show();       
        }  
    }
  showImages(amount);

}

randomPhoto('.gallery',5);
var loop = setInterval(function(){randomPhoto('.gallery',5)}, 4100);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get each `.gallery` to refresh at a different time?

Comment: That would be nice as well, and I planned to add an offset, but right now I'm just trying to get each to have 5 photos visible instead of splitting between the 2.